# RMTP video streaming in Android

Tags: android

I have the following URL: rtmp://95.87.101.64:1935/live/mtv-ifilm-ifilm-live-16x9-SDq

I want to stream this video live in my Android mobile and my code for live streaming is

```
MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(VideoViewActivity.this);
mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
// Get the URL from String VideoURL
Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
Log.e("Video uri", "" + video);
videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
videoview.setVideoURI(video);

videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    // Close the progress bar and play the video
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        videoview.start();
    }
});
```

but I am not able to play the video and when I check the logcat I found this error

> 09-09 14:43:19.887: E/MediaPlayer(11277): Error (1,-2147483648)

but when I change the video URL to rtmp://bomtv.5centscdn.com:1935/asianetmovie/c1c120277d434ca3b8a2d3bdf654dcba.sdp
it works perfectly.

Please help where I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the video format of these both files?

Comment: I don't know the exact format of both these file.

Comment: Because some video formats are not supported in videoview on older android versions(in some new versions too) so better ou could try custom video view as [Vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/)

Comment: ok i got the point, thanks for your help

Comment: so can i post the comment as answer? so it could help others?

Comment: I ask the admin for the format and he told me that format are FFmpeg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60885/discussion-between-user3649775-and-vigneshearan-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because some video formats are not supported in videoview on older android versions(in some new versions too) so better ou could try custom video view as [Vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/)